# SQL Server concurrency and generated sequence

Tags: sql-server, architecture, stored-procedures, concurrency

I need a sequence of numbers for an application, and I am hoping to leverage the abilities of SQL Server to do it. I have created the following table and procedure (in SQL Server 2005):

```
CREATE TABLE sequences (
  seq_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  seq_value int NOT NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE nextval
  @seq_name varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @seq_value INT

  SET @seq_value = -1

  UPDATE sequences
  SET @seq_value = seq_value = seq_value + 1
  WHERE seq_name = @seq_name

  RETURN @seq_value
END
```

I am a little concerned that without locking the table/row another request could happen concurrently and end up returning the same number to another thread or client. This would be very bad obviously. Is this design safe in this regard? Is there something I can add that would add the necessary locking to make it safe?

Note: I am aware of IDENTITY inserts in SQL Server - and that is not what I am looking for this in particular case. Specifically, I don't want to be inserting/deleting rows. This is basically to have a central table that manages the sequential number generator for a bunch of sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UPDATE will lock the row exclusively so your concurrency concerns are not founded. But use of @variable assignment in UPDATE statements is relying on undefined behavior. It's true, it will work, but rather rely on defined behavior: use the OUTPUT clause.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nextval
  @seq_name varchar(50)
 , @seq_value INT output
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @ot TABLE (seq_value INT)

  UPDATE sequences
  SET seq_value = seq_value + 1
  OUTPUT INSERTED.seq_value INTO @ot
  WHERE seq_name = @seq_name

  SELECT @seq_value = seq_value FROM @ot;
END
```

Comment: btw, make sure sequences is clustered indexed by seq_name

Comment: Thank you for the excellent information beyond just answering the question!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Item_Category_Details


@Item_Category varchar(20)
,@Active VARCHAR(10)

AS 

DECLARE @Item_Category_Code varchar(20)
DECLARE @seqNo AS INTEGER
SELECT @seqNo=ISNULL(Item_Code,0) FROM Seq_Master
SET @seqNo=@seqNo+1
SET @Item_Category_Code=@seqNo

PRINT @Item_Category_Code

INSERT Item_Category_Master
(Item_Category_Code
,Item_Category
,Active
)
VALUES
(
@Item_Category_Code
,@Item_Category
,@Active
)
UPDATE Seq_Master SET Item_Code=@seqNo
```